# env command not working with find command

Tags: python, linux, shell

Im trying to write a script:
`env PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH: $Dir/scripts find * -name ‘*.py' -exec pylint (} \\; | grep . && exit 1`

The code is finding all scripts in the root directory instead of using the environmental variables I set. Any help on writing this code to only look for files in the directory I set as a value in PYTHONPATH.

Comment: Your command just adds a colon to the value of `PYTHONPATH` and then runs the command `$Dir/scripts` in this modified environment. There is no invocation of `find` in the code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

`env PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH: $Dir/scripts` isn't doing what you think it's doing. Including `$PYTHONPATH` includes the former value of `PYTHONPATH`, meaning whatever you have it already set to or a blank default. The space in your variable also makes it invalid, and instead interprets the `$Dir/scripts` as a new command. It looks like what you want would be `env PYTHONPATH=$Dir/scripts` — but there's actually an easier way.

If you have `__init__.py` files in your directory, you can just do `pylint ./some-directory`. If you don't, you can use `xargs`: `﻿find . -type f -name "*.py" | xargs pylint`. If you wanted to pass the directory instead of have it coded to `.` (your current calling directory) you could do that too:

```bash
# set directory to first argument
dir="$1"
# check if "dir" was actually provided, if not, set to `.`
if [ -z "$dir" ]; then dir=.; fi
﻿find "$dir" -type f -name "*.py" | xargs pylint
```

You could save that in a script or function and then call it either with a directory (like `run-pylint-on-everything.sh ~/foo/bar`, or not, in which case it would run starting from your current shell location.

Answer (score 0):

There’s no space between the PYTHONPATH value, it was a typo mistake, I want to run the command on a CLI instead of a script.